Группировка строк, что бы сумма по каждой группе была меньше 100
Есть таблица вида

Необходимо сгруппировать строки так, что бы в каждой группе сумма cnt была  максильно близка к 100, но не больше.
На выходе должна получится таблица вида. Строки разбиты по группа, и сумма cnt в каждой группе не больше 100. Можно использовать pl/sql, вспомогательные таблицы. Пока ни чего лучше перебора всех строк в цикле while не придумал(


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Что понимается под группировкой? Добавьте в вопрос ожидаемый результат

Даже интересно, возможно ли такое чисто на SQL сделать. Подпишусь на комментарии )

Изменил описание. Не обязательно на чистом SQL. Функционал новый, ограничений особых нет

сколько ожидается чисел на входе?  а то на 9 числах ваш алгоритм может успевать за разумное время, а на 99 числах зависнет очень надолго

Вот по этому через while и не хочется. На вход ожидается до 50 строк.

а сколько получится групп? тоже до 50?

Ну без WHILE наверное особо никуда, однако, 50 строк это же копейки. Мне получилось сделать задуманное с помощью PL/SQL и коллекций. Конечно смотрится адово и нет проверок на возможные "лучшие" комбинации. Зато при обходе коллекции и при нахождении нужного значения, она уже в переборе не участвует.

Перебор коллекции из 1000 элементов(строк) - в среднем 0.07 - 0.08 сек

А можно код увидеть?)

@SwaD Ваше решение даёт строго оптимальный вариант, или просто близкий к нему? Иными словами - возможны ли исходные данные, при которых оптимальное решение даёт на 1 группу меньше, чем ваш код?

@Akina Думаю, что да. Там нет какой то логики, просто линейный сбор(сумма) поке не будет 100. Ща покажу код, а там смотрите.

@SwaD То есть используется жадный алгоритм? Или вообще "берём первый попавшийся"? Кстати, оба алгоритма должны просто "взлетать" на обычном рекурсивном CTE...

@Akina Берем первые попавшиеся, если сумма не больше 100. Простыми селектами думал, но вот как при каждом следующем исключать предыдущее не придумал сходу. А коллекции показались мне подходящими под данную задачу, особенно, если надо будет усложить логику

Учитывая, что CNT - целое число от 1 до 100, можно сделать поиск пошагово-оптимального решения динамическим программированием.  То есть, на каждом шаге мы строим следующую локально-оптимальную группу (из ещё не вошедших в группы строк) с наиближайшей к 100 суммой, но общее кол-во групп при этом может не быть оптимальным.

Выбрать данные с группировкой по группам в сумму 100 можно, допустим, вот таким образом:
DECLARE
  TYPE r_type IS RECORD(ID NUMBER, cnt NUMBER);
  TYPE t_type IS TABLE OF r_type;
  list_num t_type; -- Создаем коллекцию
  -- Всякие счетчики
  i NUMBER := 1;
  i_in NUMBER := 1;
  groupid NUMBER := 1; -- Номер начальной группы
  delta NUMBER := 0;

  -- Пишет строку в финальную таблицу и удаляет элемент из коллекции
  PROCEDURE upd_res_table(iid NUMBER, groupid NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO swad_table_res (tid, cnt, grp)
      VALUES (list_num(iid).id, list_num(iid).cnt, groupid);
      list_num.delete(iid);
    END;
BEGIN
  list_num := t_type(); -- Инициализировали коллекцию

  FOR cur IN (SELECT * FROM swad_table ORDER BY cnt DESC) -- Сортируем по количеству вниз
    LOOP -- Тут наполняем ее
      list_num.extend;
      list_num(i).id := cur.tid;
      list_num(i).cnt := cur.cnt;
      i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;

  -- тут мы на 1м элементе коллекции i_in = 1

  WHILE TRUE
    LOOP
      delta := 100 - list_num(i_in).cnt; -- Считаем, сколько осталось
     

      upd_res_table(i_in, groupid); -- Пишем данные в таблицу
      i_in := list_num.NEXT(i_in); -- Берем следющий номер коллекции
      IF (i_in IS NULL) THEN -- Если i_in null выходим из цикла
        EXIT;
      END IF;

      WHILE TRUE
        LOOP
          IF (delta - list_num(i_in).cnt >= 0) THEN -- Если можно положить в группу, гладем
            delta := delta - list_num(i_in).cnt; -- меняем остаток
            upd_res_table(i_in, groupid); -- пишем
            IF (delta < 1) THEN -- Если остаток 0, выходим из цикла
              EXIT;
            END IF;
          END IF;
         
          i_in := list_num.NEXT(i_in); -- берем следующий элемент коллекции
          IF (i_in IS NULL) THEN -- если его нет, выходим
            EXIT;
          END IF;
        END LOOP; -- Законцили цикл по заполнению группы
      groupid := groupid + 1; -- Увеличиваем группу
      i_in := list_num.FIRST; -- Берем первый элемент коллекции
      IF (i_in IS NULL) THEN -- Если пусто, выходим
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;

Время выполнения, у меня, на 100 строках, в среднем 0.008 - 0.013 с
DDL и DML таблиц
CREATE TABLE swad_table(
  tid NUMBER,
  cnt NUMBER
);
/
CREATE TABLE swad_table_res(
  tid NUMBER,
  cnt NUMBER,
  grp NUMBER
);
/
DECLARE
 mx NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT NVL(MAX(tID), 0) INTO mx FROM swad_table;
  FOR x IN 1..100 LOOP
    INSERT INTO swad_table VALUES(mx + x,ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 100)));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

--SELECT * FROM swad_table;
--SELECT * FROM swad_table_res;
--TRUNCATE TABLE swad_table;
--TRUNCATE TABLE swad_table_res

В первом варианте скрипта было 2 коллекции. Вторая результирующая наполнялась, а потом был insert в физическую таблицу.
Если расширять алгоритм и как то пытаться в пачку воткнуть близкое к 100 перебирая все возможные комбинации, то можно по аналогии создать нужные коллеции и играться с ними.
